# OpenCV - Extracting SIFT/SURF descriptor from pre-cropped patches

Tags: opencv, sift, surf

I have a set of 100K 64x64 gray patches (that are already aligned, meaning they all have the same orientation) and I would like to extract a SIFT descriptor from each one using OpenCV.

It is clear to me all I need to do is to define a vector with one keypoint kp such that: kp.x=32, kp.y=32.

However, I don't know how to set the kp.size parameter. From going over SIFT's code, it looks as it's doing some non-trivial calculations with that parameter instead of just assuming that it's the size of the patch.

Question 1: what should be the kp.size parameter when extracting SIFT descriptors from patches of size 64x64?

Question 2: what should be the kp.size parameter when extracting SURF descriptors from patches of size 64x64?

Comment: have a look at 1. original SIFT/SURF papers how feature scale and descriptor size are linked. 2. openCV code whether they use the same computation. Or you could just modify openCV SIFT/SURF code to print scale and descriptor size and test some values ;)

Comment: https://github.com/hpatches/hpatches-benchmark/blob/master/python/extract_opencv_sift.py#L43 here is script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [sift](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) original publication, the scale of the keypoint is used to weight the histogram of gradients magnitude and orientations(paragraph 6. The local image descriptor). So in your case, since the grey patches are aligned, it is up to you to decide if you want to weight the contributions of the pixels further from the patch center or not, and select the scale (i.e. the with of the gaussian weighting window) accordingly.

For SURF, it's basically the same principle except that instead of gradient magnitude the response to haar wavelet is use, but you could still weight those responses with a gaussian window.

Also, since you are working with those aligned patches I would advise you not to use the high-level functions of OpenCV, but to simply use/recode the descriptor extraction part, and to apply any weighting you want to compute your patch representation. One reason to do so is that, in the SIFT example, the computation of SIFT descriptors might "add new keypoints" to the one you provided, if the algorithm is "not happy" with the keypoint orientation, it duplicates the keypoint at the same location but different orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. So the SIFT descriptor uses a neighbourhood of 4x4 grids usually, each grid usually being 4x4 pixels. Therefore the neighbourhood in pixels is usually 16x16. The scale/size is the parameter to determine the amount of downsampling/blurring/radius of keypoint. So I would think in your case, this would be **4**.

You probably would also know that SIFT keypoints also work on sub-pixel layers. (32,32) would not be the exact center of your image patch, which would actually be (32.5, 32.5) if your image dimensions (x,y) start from 1. If they start from 0, it would be (31.5, 31.5)- as in the case of opencv.